# How to add sharepoint site on another port?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013, iis7

When trying to deploy my sharepoint site I get:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool':
>   Cannot connect to the SharePoint site:. Make sure that this is a valid
>   URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer

The deployment from vs.net 2013 works fine normally, the only thing I changed was adding a portnr in the siteurl property. How can I deploy/add another site on another port?

Comment: you try to retract the solution which is deployed on the first site and then change the url of the site and you can also provide the port and re deploy the solution on the new site which you want to deploy. Make sure the url you mention in the Alternate access mapping in central admin.